# iOS 8.3 - EXC_BAD_ACCESS in CoreGraphics Image Drawing

Tags: ios, memory-management, core-graphics, cgcontext, symbolicatecrash

In my application, I have a CoreGraphics image drawing module. The application is crashing randomly at *CGContextAddPath()* function call. The path is a *CGPathRef* object created using *CGPathCreateMutable()* function call. The sample code is given below:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if (touching) return;

    //start a new path
    path = CGPathCreateMutable();
    //set the path's starting point
    UITouch *touch = (UITouch *)[touches anyObject];
    CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, [touch locationInView:m_view].x, [touch locationInView:m_view].y);

    touching = YES;
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if (touching){
        //get the current location of the touch event
        UITouch *theTouch = (UITouch *)[touches anyObject];
        pathPoint = [theTouch locationInView:m_view];   
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, pathPoint.x, pathPoint.y);     
        [canvasLayer setNeedsDisplay];
    }
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if (!touching) return;

    //create a new image context
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(backgroundLayer.bounds.size.width,  backgroundLayer.bounds.size.height));

    //grab a reference to the new image context
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    //push the image context to the top of the drawing stack
    UIGraphicsPushContext(ctx); 
    //set the blend mode to prevent white pixels from
    //covering up the lines that have already been drawn
    CGContextSetBlendMode(ctx, kCGBlendModeDarken);

    if (cacheImage != nil) {
        //draw the cached state of the image to the image context and release it
        [cacheImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, backgroundLayer.bounds.size.width, backgroundLayer.bounds.size.height)];
    }

    //blend the drawing layer into the image context
    [canvasLayer drawInContext:ctx];
    //we're done drawing to the image context
    UIGraphicsPopContext();
    //store the image context so we can add to it again later
    cacheImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    //we're finished with the image context altogether
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    touching = NO;
    //release the path
    CGPathRelease(path);

    //update the background layer (we'll need to draw the cached image to the background)
    [backgroundLayer setNeedsDisplay];
 }

- (void)drawLayer:(CATiledLayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx {
    //this method is handling multiple layers, so first
    //determine which layer we're drawing to
    if (layer == canvasLayer) {
        if (!touching) return;

        //add the path to the context
        CGContextAddPath(ctx, path); /***Exception points to this line***/
        //set a line width and draw the path
        CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 6.0f);//---thikness of line
        CGContextStrokePath(ctx);
    }
    else if (layer == backgroundLayer) {
        //remember the current state of the context
        CGContextSaveGState(ctx);
        //the cached image coordinate system is upside down, so do a backflip
        CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0, backgroundLayer.bounds.size.height);
        CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1.0, -1.0);
        //draw the image
        CGImageRef ref = cacheImage.CGImage;
        CGContextDrawImage(ctx, backgroundLayer.bounds, ref);
        //restore the context to its pre-flipped state
        CGContextRestoreGState(ctx);
    }
}
```

The diagnostics crash report obtained from the device shows:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Subtype: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x090d3330
Triggered by Thread:  13

    Thread 13 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-qos
Thread 13 Crashed:
0   ???                                  0x090d3330 0 + 151860016
1   CoreGraphics                         0x22886b6c 0x22874000 + 76652
2   CoreGraphics                         0x228a036e 0x22874000 + 181102
3   MyApplication                        0x001c8062 0xb6000 + 1122402
4   QuartzCore                           0x256d08fc 0x25695000 + 243964
5   QuartzCore                           0x257a9e86 0x25695000 + 1134214
6   QuartzCore                           0x256fdd14 0x25695000 + 429332
7   libdispatch.dylib                    0x30f99866 0x30f8b000 + 59494
8   libdispatch.dylib                    0x30f9a89e 0x30f8b000 + 63646
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x3110eda6 0x3110e000 + 3494
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x3110eaf8 0x3110e000 + 2808
```

When I symbolicate the memory addresses in crash report, the exception points to *CGContextAddPath(ctx, path);*. Is it caused by explicit release of the path using *CGPathRelease(path);*? If I comment out the release function, the application does not crash, however will it introduce a memory leak?

Answer (score 1):

You destroy the path in touchEnded, but drawLayer may get called after that.

Comment: we create the path object in touchesBegan() and release it in touchesEnded() function after ending image context. In which case can drawLayer() function be called after we destroy the path object?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are doing but usually windows, views and layers may get updated even if you don't touch them or force the update with setNeedsDisplay.